# Submit ipa file to itunes connect

Tags: ios, iphone, png, phonegap-build

I build an `ipa` using `adobe.phonegap.build`. Now I want to submit this file to itunesconnect using Application Loader. While submitting ipa in the application loader I'm getting errors:

> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format.

How can I fix this? I'm using the same `config.xml` file for both Android and iOS app builds.

Comment: Maybe you can add the content of your config.xml to your post. It also looks like there is a problem with the built of different `phonegap` versions. But looks to me like `phonegap` does produce this problem on several versions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this post](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/missing_recommended_icon_file), looks like he had the same problem.
Looks like you images inside your project, where the size is wrong or some of them are missing. Like apple [lists the icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) they need, you should be sure you have all pictures inside your project.

**Somebody else just posted this:**

> I just encountered the warning for the image sizes of 76x76, 120x120, and 152x152. It seems to be a new thing with iOS 7 as I built my app using PhoneGap 3.1. I created images of these sizes and added this to my config.xml:

```
<icon src="images/icon-certify-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76"/> 
<icon src="images/icon-certify-120.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120"/> 
<icon src="images/icon-certify-152.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.It provides all the icon formats.

Comment: But did this fix your problem or do you still get the error on uploading the app?

Comment: It fixes the problem but new one arises... in Phonegap build android apk is not generated b'coz of icon parameters(`<icon src="images/icon-certify-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76"/> 
`) in config file.